# Jquery CPU usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, cpu-usage

I am using Jquery to make an image scroll across my page horizontally. The only problem is that it uses a serious amount of cpu usage. Up to 100% on a single core laptop in firefox.
What could cause this???

Jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $(".speech").animate({backgroundPosition: "-6000px 0px"}, 400000, null);
    });

    </script>
```

CSS

```
.speech {
    /*position:fixed;*/
    top:0;
    left:0px;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    background:url(/images/speech.png) -300px -500px repeat-x;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="speech"></div>
```

Comment: Crikey really? I've never come across such a memory hog. What browser are you using? I can't replicate the problem. Try the same thing but don't use a png - try a gif/jpg instead and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: He didn't say it was a memory hog; that's not what 100% CPU utilization means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's using up CPU resources because you're asking the browser to repaint an image many times per second over a long period of time.  That's not free.

Answer (score 11):

In-case anyone is looking for a solution to high CPU usage when using jQuery animations (as I was) then it's worth noting that [jQuery.fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/) was added to jQuery 1.4.3 so you can control the animation interval rate.

Example of use (setting this to around 50-70 kept my animations smooth and I noticed CPU usage dropped down to about 10-20%):

jQuery.fx.interval = 50;

Answer (score 0):

If this is a memory-cpu related issue then you can nullify the result of the jQuery function call. If your call returns a jQuery Object then after the call you can set it to null:

```
var tmp = $(".speech").animate({backgroundPosition: "-6000px 0px"}, 400000, null);
});
tmp = null;
```

Note: If this IS in ANY WAY related with the memory leak then it has to do with circular references
and by setting to null you can break it.

Give it a try, i would like to know the results if you have the time to post.

Comment: That's going to do no good whatsoever. The problem described is one of CPU load during the animation. Freeing the jQuery object after the animation will not affect the process of the animation itself.

Comment: So you can leave out any issues related with memory. I would go into the animate function implementation details and check for issues, i would also make sure that the function/method contract params are understood. If animation is important in your application i would suggest looking around for JS libraries that focus on animations. There might be a plugin or extension in jQuery that handles animation in a better way. Sorry for doing no good...sometimes we need a place to start and find our way to the target after dismissing factors one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is by using a plugin such as http://www.spritely.net/download/